# Before each describe in Cypress/mocha?

Tags: mocha.js, cypress

`before` runs before all tests in a describe block.
`beforeEach` runs before each test in a describe block.

Is there anything that runs *before each describe block* nested within an outer describe block?

Note: My React project is originally set up with Jest. I later added Cypress. When using `expect` assertions in my Cypress tests, I have to use Mocha syntax rather than Jest syntax (`.to.eq()` rather than `toEqual()`), though I suspect that my `describe`s and `it`s are being called from Jest (if that makes any sense).

Answer (score 0):

You can use beforeEach outside of a describe block to make it a "root level hook". Here's the documentation I found that demonstrates this.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html#Hooks

Comment: Could you edit your answer to provide a basic code example to demonstrate how this might work? That would be useful.

Answer (score -2):

There is no relation I see here for your Application Under Test(AUT) and Cypress, except the fact that you are using Cypress to test your react app(AUT).

You can leave Jest as your dev team is using Jest for their unit tests. But as far as the Cypress tests concern, you have Cypress which is bundled with Mocha framework and Chai already so you can write Mocha tests.

So better you use Mocha style tests and assertions. Do not mix the jest & mocha with cypress.

Comment: Cypress actually doesn't have support for Jest. So far it has support to Mocha only and it will work only when they extend their support. That is why ii saiid do not mix Cypress with Jest... May be my comment was not constructed properly...

Comment: I understand. I don't actually know what's happening when I use `describe`, but I do know that sometimes when I type `beforeEach` it adds an import for `beforeEach` **from mocha**, which doesn't appear to respect the `describe` scope (which I guess makes sense if the describe scope is coming from jest). Still, everything works fine, and still, this isn't an answer to my question.